# How to compress the response output from Maximo JSON api

Tags: maximo

Is there a way to compress the output from Maximo(7.6.0.4) JSON api. I have gone  through the Maximo JSON api documentation, but there is no mention of any parameter that can be used to achieve this.

Comment: you can use `&lean=1` to reduce some of the unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried sending `_compact=true` parameter on the URL? If you're actually wanting compression (i.e. "zipping"), as opposed to the JSON just not being "pretty" by having whitespace removed, then you should be looking at GZIP settings in IBM HTTP Server's httpd.conf.

Comment: _compact=true is not applicable for the new JSON API available since 7.6.0.2 [link] (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20Maximo%20Asset%20Management/page/Maximo%20JSON%20API). It is part of old REST api. As you mentioned, I am actually looking to compress (zip). I will take a look at httpd.conf. Thanks